# Console.ReadLine() max length?

Tags: c#

When running a small piece of C# code, when I try to input a long string into `Console.ReadLine()` it seems to cut off after a couple of lines.

Is there a max length to Console.Readline(), if so is there a way to increase that?
[image]

Comment: "after a couple of lines"? ReadLine() should only return 1 line! ;D

Comment: @Jeffrey: Sorry, I mean in a normal cmd.exe console size, it is a few lines with wrap around :-)

Comment: @Jeffrey: Added image to show you want I mean, it won't let my type any more 'a' characters then seen in that screenshot.

Comment: /* Console.ReadLine() maximum is 254*/ Console.WriteLine("Length = " + Console.ReadLine().Length);  // StreamReader can read in a whole lot more. It can read in several thousand characters in once

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Without any modifications to the code it will only take a maximum of 256 characters ie; It will allow 254 to be entered and will reserve 2 for CR and LF.

The following method will help to increase the limit:

```
private static string ReadLine()
    {
        Stream inputStream = Console.OpenStandardInput(READLINE_BUFFER_SIZE);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[READLINE_BUFFER_SIZE];
        int outputLength = inputStream.Read(bytes, 0, READLINE_BUFFER_SIZE);
        //Console.WriteLine(outputLength);
        char[] chars = Encoding.UTF7.GetChars(bytes, 0, outputLength);
        return new string(chars);
    }
```

Comment: Nice solution. For an alternative, see [this later answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6081967/1336654) to a duplicate of the question here on SO. It uses `Console.SetIn` to change the "in" stream.

Comment: When i tried to do this with a base64 encoded string, some of it got turned into chinese characters, went for ara's answer

Answer (score 35):

An issue with stack72's answer is that if the code is used in a batch-script the input is no longer line buffered. I found an alternative version at [averagecoder.net](http://averagecoder.net/how-to-get-user-input-and-allowing-more-than-256-characters-to-be-entered-on-net-console-application.htm) that keeps the ReadLine call. Note that StreamReader also must have a length argument, since it has a fixed buffer as well.

```
byte[] inputBuffer = new byte[1024]; 
Stream inputStream = Console.OpenStandardInput(inputBuffer.Length);
Console.SetIn(new StreamReader(inputStream, Console.InputEncoding, false, inputBuffer.Length));
string strInput = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: There are no words.  I love you.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to create an array (inputBuffer) just to use the .Length property. Petr Matas' answer is exactly the same, except that it doesn't use a confusing/unused array.

Comment: How do you get a character count higher than 1024? I've tried higher numbers yet 1024 always seems to be the limit.

Answer (score 24):

This is a simplified version of [ara's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8048103/2399343) and it works for me.

```
int bufSize = 1024;
Stream inStream = Console.OpenStandardInput(bufSize);
Console.SetIn(new StreamReader(inStream, Console.InputEncoding, false, bufSize));

string line = Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 24):

This is a simplified version of [Petr Matas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18203115/189011).
Basically you can specify the buffer size only once as follow :

```
Console.SetIn(new StreamReader(Console.OpenStandardInput(),
                               Console.InputEncoding,
                               false,
                               bufferSize: 1024));
string line = Console.ReadLine();
```

Because in the end

```
Console.OpenStandardInput(int bufferSize)
```

calls

```
private static Stream GetStandardFile(int stdHandleName, FileAccess access, int bufferSize)
```

which doesn't use [bufferSize](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs) !

Answer (score 9):

`Console.ReadLine()` has a 254 character limit.

I found the below **single** line of code [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/51ad87c5-92a3-4bb3-8385-bf66a48d6953/how-to-read-more-than-254-characters-from-the-console?forum=csharpgeneral). That seemed to do the trick.

> Console.SetIn(new StreamReader(Console.OpenStandardInput(8192)));

Answer (score 1):

ReadLine() internally reads character by character until a -1 or '\n' or '\r\n' is encountered.

```
    public virtual String ReadLine()
    { 
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (true) { 
            int ch = Read(); 
            if (ch == -1) break;
            if (ch == '\r' || ch == '\n') 
            {
                if (ch == '\r' && Peek() == '\n') Read();
                return sb.ToString();
            } 
            sb.Append((char)ch);
        } 
        if (sb.Length > 0) return sb.ToString(); 
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps I am hitting a cmd.exe limitation?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a limitation of the Windows console. You should try putting your input into a file, and then piping the file into the application. I am not certain if that will work, but it has a chance.

```
regex_text.exe < my_test_data.txt
```

Comment: 'Redirection is not supported'

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your OS, the command line input will only accept 8191 characters for XP and 2047 characters for NT and Windows 2000. I suggest you pass a filename instead which has your long input and read that file.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a matter of seeing the entire output of the text in the Console, I have found that the following code works to display it:

```
Console.SetBufferSize(128, 1024);
```

Comment: Make sure you are using it within a method block.

Answer (score -1):

Save the input into text and use StreamReader.

```
using System;

using System.IO;

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    try
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\Test\\temp.txt");
        Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine().Length);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
    }
}
```