# Why does Console.Readline() have a limit on the length of text it allows?

Tags: c#, console-application

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Console.Readline() max length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557889/console-readline-max-length)

In [my attempt](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/conversation/this-is-why-i-cant-have-nice-things) to find a very simple text to speech application [I decided it was faster to write my own](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/message/627468?plain=true). I noticed, however, that [`Console.Readline()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline.aspx) is limited in the amount of text it allows per line to 254 characters; I can't find anything about this limit in the method documentation.

Is this a limitation in the Windows stack, or a problem with my code? How can I overcome it? I could decide to read character by character with [`Console.Readkey()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85.aspx), but won't I then risk losing characters to the MS DOS dumb text pasting behavior?

Comment: Please note I understand where 254 must come from - that's 256 bytes, minus a new line and the feed return. I don't know where that 256 came from, however.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quick look at implementation with .NET Reflector gives this:

```
public static Stream OpenStandardInput()
{
    return OpenStandardInput(0x100);
}

public static Stream OpenStandardInput(int bufferSize)
{
  ...
}
```

256 is the default value of OpenStandardInput, so I guess it's by design. Note this is only for .NET as the Windows API does not have this limit.

Answer (score 48):

This is a somewhat bizarre limitation on the Console API. I had this problem before and found the following solutions:

```
Console.SetIn(new StreamReader(Console.OpenStandardInput(8192)));
```

From the following MSDN forum post:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/51ad87c5-92a3-4bb3-8385-bf66a48d6953

See also this related StackOverflow question:

[Console.ReadLine() max length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557889/console-readline-max-length)

Comment: for me I needed the following: Console.SetIn(new StreamReader(Console.OpenStandardInput(8192), Console.InputEncoding, false, 8192));