# C#: Large amounts of text cut off when read by program

Tags: c#, arrays, string, console.writeline

Hi I cant seem to find any useful information regarding how to store information into an array from a console.writeline.

```
 Console.WriteLine("Please enter one or more sentences.");
 string text = Console.ReadLine();
```

How would I store the users sentence into an array? as currently if I enter a large amount of text it is getting cut of hopefully an array will allow for all of the text to be read and sorted.
Thank you!!

Comment: You're falling into the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your problem is: "currently if I enter a large amount of text it is getting cut of"; You should state this as your problem instead of asking how to implement an assumed solution. `Console.WriteLine` has nothing to do with `Console.ReadLine`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback should be resolved now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a limit of the Console API, it is 256 characters (254 + CR LF).
You can change this limit with

```
Console.SetIn(new StreamReader(Console.OpenStandardInput(8192)));
```

Found on MSDN forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/51ad87c5-92a3-4bb3-8385-bf66a48d6953

OR

you can create a new ReadLine method, check this post:
[Console.ReadLine() max length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557889/console-readline-max-length)

Comment: I found similar information is on the [`Console.ReadLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) MSDN page. The method itself can read up to Int32.MaxValue, but as the page says it reads from a buffer and that buffer is by default only 256 characters long.

Answer (score 1):

You can establish an way of communication with the user, like when he send an empty line it ends. And then do the following:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter one or more sentences.");
string text;    
List<string> list = new List();

while (true) 
{
       text = Console.ReadLine();

      if (text.Length == 0)
          break;
      else
          list.Add(text);             
}
```