# How do I increase the 254 character limit in a console application?

Tags: vb.net, buffer, console-application

I'm trying to write a console application and I want to paste quite a significant amount of data. However, I'm currently limited to the 254 character limit. Is there a way to increase this limit with VB.Net?

The only solutions that I have came across are for c# or forms, but I'm writing in console only.

Answer (score 1):

There are many similar questions and answers for C# like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557889/console-readline-max-length), but for some reason nothing for VB. However, it pretty easy to convert the code from C# to VB. Here is a conversion of the best answer I found:

```
Console.SetIn(New StreamReader(Console.OpenStandardInput(8192)))
Dim line As String = Console.ReadLine()
```

The `Console.SetIn()` allows you to change the `TextReader` for the `Console`. The value `8192` is the buffer size. Some answers suggest setting it to `1024` (1KB), but perhaps `8192` (8KB) works better for this purpose.