# Inserting a very large integer array as standard input

Tags: c#

I want to be able to insert an `array` of `integer` as standard input which can has a length of **1000000**.
I am trying to do that using this code but the `array` will be only a size of **254**, *(I read from an article that Console.ReadLine take only 254 charecter)*.

**Note:** Every character of the `array` is between `1 to 6`
and the first line of the code `numThrows` represents the `length` of the array.

```
 int numThrows = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); // length of array
 string str = Console.ReadLine();
 int[] arr = new int[numThrows];
 arr = str.Select(c => Convert.ToInt32(c.ToString())).ToArray();
```

Comment: [Console.SetIn()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.setin). What would the content of this array represent? How are you planning to input it? Pasting *something*?

Comment: this array represents the throws of a dice, as every digit will be between 1 and 6, I am planning to create an array of million digits to try it.

Comment: you can read it from file generate them randomly in your code... how you are supposed to write all the `10000` integers on CMD ... :/

Comment: I know it seems strange, but it is homework for college, and they say it will be tested with an array that contains a million digits, and this was asked to be solved using standard input and output

Comment: "I read from an article that Console.ReadLine take only 254 charecter" -- Hmm, I just tested this. It seams I can read more than 1000000 characters with a single `ReadLine()`. Where did you read this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557889/console-readline-max-length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase the limit by writing your own ReadLine function.

```
        const int BufferLimit = 10000;
        public static string ReadLine()
        {
            Stream s = Console.OpenStandardInput(BufferLimit);
            byte[] Buffer = new byte[BufferLimit];
            int Length = s.Read(Buffer, 0, BufferLimit);
            return new string(Encoding.UTF7.GetChars(Buffer, 0, Length));
        }
```