# Why can I read more than 254 characters with Console.ReadLine when the docs suggest that I shouldn't be able to?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, console, console.readline

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=netcore-3.1#remarks) for `Console.ReadLine` say:

> By default, the method reads input from a 256-character input buffer. Because this includes the Environment.NewLine character(s), the method can read lines that contain up to 254 characters. To read longer lines, call the OpenStandardInput(Int32) method.

However, I can read more than that many characters just fine. Running a simple program like:

```
string s = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine(s);
Console.WriteLine(s.Length);

Console.ReadKey();
```

with an input like:

```
aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbccccccccccddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeffffffffffgggggggggghhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiiijjjjjjjjjjaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbccccccccccddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeffffffffffgggggggggghhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiiijjjjjjjjjjaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbccccccccccddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeffffffffffgggggggggghhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiiijjjjjjjjjjaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbccccccccccddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeffffffffffgggggggggghhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiiijjjjjjjjjjaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbccccccccccddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeffffffffffgggggggggghhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiiijjjjjjjjjj
```

yields the same input back with length 500.

Runnable example [here](https://repl.it/repls/AttachedUnusualMemory).

Are the docs outdated then, or are the words "by default" key here?

---

**An update:**
Jeremy found a limit of 4096 defined in the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Console/src/System/Console.cs#L20).

I have verified that a .NET Core app will only read the first 4094 characters from stdin (excluding newlines).

In my case, I actually have a .NET Core 3.1 process that starts a .NET Framework 4.6 process, redirecting its StandardOut and StandardIn. I have verified that the .NET Framework process can successfully read 1 billion characters via `Console.ReadLine()` where the .NET Core 3.1 process sends the Framework process stuff via `fwProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(Serialize(<some stuff>));`

This also works when the .NET Framework process is replaced with a .NET Core process.

So it seems like the 256-character limit doesn't apply when redirecting stdout/stdin, but if someone can dig up the definitive proof/docs explaining this, I would appreciate it. If there is still a limit (excluding the OutOfMemory case), but it's 1.1 billion characters, I would like to know. I'd also like to know if this is platform dependent (I'm on Windows 10).

If it helps, this is the code that I'm running.

ConsoleApp1:

```
ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    FileName = "ConsoleApp2.exe",
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardInput = true
};

StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
var proc = Process.Start(processInfo);

int n = 1_000_000_000;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    s.Append("a");

proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(s.ToString());
string s = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine(s.Length == n); // logs True

Console.ReadKey();
```

ConsoleApp2:

```
string s = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: specifically https://stackoverflow.com/a/5558123/1704458

Comment: I'm using win10 running .Net Core 3.1. Look through Console.In, there is a private property _maxCharsPerBuffer = 16384. Not sure if this is varied across platform, Microsoft may state a "least" size in document?

Comment: @T.S. Well, my question is different from that one. I'm not asking if there is a max length. I'm asking why I don't have the limit that's documented

Comment: @T.S. Well, I guess the body of the question is a bit different from the title. I suppose it's more related to mine than I thought

Comment: Related github issue? https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29029

Comment: @T.S. The specific answer you linked to doesn't seem to apply in my case. I can send over 60 thousand characters over. maybe has something to do with the fact that I'm redirecting stdin/stdout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paraphrasing from [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29029):

> The default cmd console mode is "ENABLE_LINE_INPUT", which means that
>   when code issues a ::ReadFile call against stdin, ::ReadFile doesn't
>   return to the caller until it encounters a carriage return. But the
>   call to ReadFile only has a limited size buffer that was passed to it.
>   Which means that cmd looks at the buffer size provided to it, and
>   determines based on that how many characters long the line can be...
>   if the line were longer, it wouldn't be able to store all the data
>   into the buffer.

The default buffer size used when opening `Console.In` is now 4096 ([source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Console/src/System/Console.cs#L20))

The documentation is open source, and [available here](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/blob/ba07c9001aa7e296027eda08c56151e170e8e28b/xml/System/Console.xml#L2530) if you would like to submit an issue or pull request.

When redirecting StandardOut/StandardIn, this limit does not apply. From [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/36212#issuecomment-593135089):

> The limit is how much memory you pass in.

Comment: thanks, this is helpful. I've updated my question to note that sending data between two net processes doesn't seem to have this limit. I can successfully read tens of thousands of chars from my .NET FW process. I'll search if there's a different limit in FW. (redirected stdin/stdout)

Comment: As I quoted in my answer, this behaviour depends on reading from an interactive console. That's where the behaviour originates. I think that .net's `Console.ReadLine` should be changed to hide this OS implementation detail and keep reading until an actual new line is found.