# How to paste large texts into the console (using C#)

Tags: c#, command-prompt

I am attempting to code something using C# where the user pastes a long string into the console, but it limits the amount I can paste.

I am hoping someone can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you saying that the user is running your console app and wants to paste text as input? Does that really have anything to do with C#? If the same would happen for other languages, it doesn't. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help, but I found the solution.

```
byte[] inputBuffer = new byte[1024]; 
Stream inputStream = Console.OpenStandardInput(inputBuffer.Length);
Console.SetIn(new StreamReader(inputStream, Console.InputEncoding, false, inputBuffer.Length));
```

Answer (score -1):

Could it possibally be the buffer size?
The console buffer size may be too small to display the entire paste.
You can increase  it's height and width  with **`Console.BufferHeight`** and **`Console.BufferWidth`**
Here is a code example
`

**Console.BufferHeight = 500;**

**Console.BufferWidth = 120;**

**Console.WriteLine("Please paste a string:");**

**string input = Console.ReadLine();**

**Console.WriteLine($"You pasted: {input}");**
`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I found the solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557889/console-readline-max-length